# GPU memory using CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap()

Tags: memory, gpu, wic

When using CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap() I can see the GPU memory usage increase. 
The code looks like:

```
hr = pRenderTarget->CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap(pImagePoolEntry->pConverter,
NULL, pImagePoolEntry->pPoolImage.GetAddressOf());

pPoolImage is defined as ComPtr<ID2D1Bitmap> pPoolImage;
```

The pPoolImage pointer hangs around for the life of using the image, when done and the pPoolImage is released I do not see the GPU memory usage decrease.

So is there a way to have the GPU release the image data? or should I not be worried. The only time I see the usage drop is when the application is terminated.

Note: I'm using GPU-Z to monitor the GPU memory usage.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with `cuda`.

Answer (score 0):

DirectX video memory destruction is deferred. You can explicitly use `IDXGIDevice3::Trim`, but generally it doesn't matter in real-world cases.

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn280346(v=vs.85).aspx)